# Filter wp_query by ACF repeater subfields and custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

On specific page I’m displaying posts from my CPT („opencourses”). Posts from this specific CPT are grouped by custom taxonomy („kategoria”). And this part works. At the same page I have four different select fields to filter the query. One dropdown is dedicated to filtering by mentioned taxonomy, rest of them are related to repeater subfields. I’ve managed to populate select fields with proper data. And this part works also great.

What I’m missing is one thing – when I’m filtering my posts, it shows entire group of posts instead THE SPECIFIC post. Hopefully below example will be more descriptive – what I get currently:

TAXONOMY_CHILD_1

- Post 1
- Post 2
- Post 3
- Post 4

What I want to get:

TAXONOMY_CHILD_1

- Post 3

It’s crucial to me just to highlight the specific posts. Taxonomy Childs are in my example types of courses. Inside specific type I have bunch of courses with different timing, location, price, so showing them at the same time is pointless.

Entire code can be found here:

```
<?php

    $taxonomy = 'typ';

        if (is_page(29557) ):
            $childno = '205';

        elseif (is_page(29640) ):
            $childno = '206';

        endif;                                      

    $args = array(
        'child_of'=> $childno,
        'childless' => true                     
    );

    $taxonomy_terms = get_terms($taxonomy, $args);


    if($taxonomy_terms) {
        foreach($taxonomy_terms as $taxonomy_term) {

            $taxquery = array('relation' => 'AND');
            $metaquery = array('relation' => 'AND');

            if(isset($_GET['obszar']) && $_GET['obszar'] != '')
            {
                $taxquery[] =  array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'kategoria',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $_GET["obszar"],
                    );
            }
            if(isset($_GET['firma']) && $_GET['firma'] != '')
            {
                $metaquery[] =  array(
                    'compare' => '=',
                    'key'    => 'terminy_warsztatow_$_firma',
                    'value'    => $_GET["firma"],
                );
            }
            if(isset($_GET['lokalizacja']) && $_GET['lokalizacja'] != '')
            {
                $metaquery[] =  array(
                    'compare' => '=',
                    'key'    => 'terminy_warsztatow_$_wojewodztwo',
                    'value'    => $_GET["lokalizacja"],
                );
            }
            if(isset($_GET['data']) && $_GET['data'] != '')
            {
                $metaquery[] =  array(
                    'compare' => '=',
                    'key'    => 'terminy_warsztatow_$_data',
                    'value'    => $_GET["data"],
                );
            }

            $args_main_query = array(
                'post_type' => 'opencourses',
                "$taxonomy" => $taxonomy_term->slug,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1, 
                'fields' => 'all',
                'tax_query' => $taxquery,
                'meta_query' => $metaquery,
            );

            $query = new WP_Query( $args_main_query );

            if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php $color = get_field('blok_szkoleniowy_kolor', $taxonomy_term); ?>

            <div class="term_anchor" id="<?php echo $taxonomy_term->slug; ?>"></div>
            <h4 class="term_blok_szkoleniowy"><span class="spacer" style="background:<?php echo $color; ?>"></span><?php echo $taxonomy_term->name; ?></h4>

                <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="coursWrapper">

                            <div class="visibleInfoCourses" style="border-left: 5px solid <?php echo $color; ?>">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                                            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a>
                                            <?php if (get_field('nowosc')) : ?><span class="labelItem labeImNew">Nowość</span><?php endif ?>
                                            <?php if (get_field('new_form')) : ?><span class="labelItem labeImNewForm">Nowa formuła</span><?php endif ?>
                                            <?php if (get_field('new_date_info')) : ?><span class="labelItem labeImNewDate">Zmiana terminu</span><?php endif ?>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                                            <div class="buttonsHereRight">
                                                <button class="btnBorderGrey btn-lean-sm">Terminy warsztatów</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                                                                                      
                            </div>

                            <div class="InvisibleInfoCourses" style="border-left: 5px solid <?php echo $color; ?>">
                                <?php if (have_rows('terminy_warsztatow')) : $i = 0; ?>
                                    <div class="TerminySzkolen" style="padding: 0;">
                                        <?php while (have_rows('terminy_warsztatow')) : the_row();
                                            $i++;
                                            $hotele = get_sub_field('polecane_hotele');
                                            $zapisy = get_sub_field('stan_zapisow'); ?>
                                            <div class="InvisibleInfoCoursesDetails" <?php if ($zapisy == 'Sprzedane') : echo " style='opacity:.6;'";endif; ?>>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                        <span><img src="<?php the_sub_field('logotyp') ?>" alt="<?php the_sub_field('lokalizacja') ?>"></span>
                                                        <span><i style="opacity: .6;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i><?php the_sub_field('data') ?></span>
                                                        <span><i style="opacity: .6;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i><?php the_sub_field('lokalizacja') ?></span>
                                                        <span><i style="opacity: .6;" class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i><?php echo $zapisy; ?></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                        <div class="buttonsHereRight">
                                                            <!-- <a class="btn-lean btn-lean-sm" target="_blank" download="Formularz zgłoszeniowy" href="<?php the_sub_field('przycisk') ?>" onclick="gtag('event', 'szkolenia', {'event_category' : 'szkolenie-otwarte-lista-szkoleń','event_label' : '<?php the_title() ?> '});" <?php if ($zapisy == 'Sprzedane') : echo " style='display:none'";endif; ?>>Zapisz się</a> -->
                                                            <!-- <a class="btn-lean btn-lean-sm" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" onclick="gtag('event', 'szkolenia', {'event_category' : 'szkolenie-otwarte-lista-szkoleń','event_label' : '<?php the_title() ?> '});" <?php if ($zapisy == 'Sprzedane') : echo " style='display:none'"; endif; ?>>Zapisz się</a> -->
                                                            <a class="btn-lean btn-lean-sm" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" <?php if ($zapisy == 'Sprzedane') : echo " style='display:none'"; endif; ?>>Zapisz się</a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>



            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // so nothin' weird happens to other loops
            endif;
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with:

```
   //Since the changed behaviour of esc_sql() in WordPress 4.8.3, 
   //cannot use the % character as a placeholder, hence need to alter 'where' close:
   function textdomain_posts_where( $where ) {
        $where = str_replace("meta_key = 'terminy_warsztatow_$", "meta_key LIKE 'terminy_warsztatow_%", $where);
        return $where;
   }
   add_filter('posts_where', 'textdomain_posts_where');



  if (isset($_GET["filtr_firma"]))
    {
        $meta_query[] =  array(
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'key'    => 'terminy_warsztatow_$_firma',
            'value'    => $_GET["filtr_firma"],
        );
    }
    if (isset($_GET["filtr_lokalizacja"]))
    {
        $meta_query[] =  array(
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'key'    => 'terminy_warsztatow_$_data',
            'value'    => $_GET["filtr_lokalizacja"],
        );
    }
    if (isset($_GET["filtr_termin"]))
    {
        $meta_query[] =  array(
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'key'    => 'terminy_warsztatow_$_wojewodztwo',
            'value'    => $_GET["filtr_termin"],
        );
    }

    ...
```

Because your repeater key stored in the database in the form

```
terminy_warsztatow_0_firma
terminy_warsztatow_0_data
terminy_warsztatow_0_wojewodztwo
---
terminy_warsztatow_1_firma
terminy_warsztatow_1_data
terminy_warsztatow_1_wojewodztwo
---
terminy_warsztatow_2_firma
terminy_warsztatow_2_data
terminy_warsztatow_2_wojewodztwo
```

Comment: well it works partially. Why partially? as mentioned, I have 4 type of filters. When I will select from dropdown any value from a single filter, in the URL after submission there will be blank values for other filters. And based on that query returns ZERO results. 

When I will remove by myself "nulled" filters and keep only the one which I've selected it will somehow work. But it will not show only single post, but a group of them (among which there is a post for which im looking for). Take a look: https://lean.colorfill.pl/szkolenia-otwarte/szkolenia-dla-produkcji/